# texlive font installation - what am I doing wrong

Tags: fonts, installing

I'm trying to install Source Sans Pro from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/sourcesanspro) on a TeX Live system. My OS/TeX system is ubuntu 12.04 "precise" and TeXLive 2009-15. I don't have root rights so I can't switch to a newer version or add an extra repository, so it'll have to be a manual installation in `~/texmf'.

I'm following all the usual steps and I've spent half a day trying to find out what I'm doing wrong (including reading StackExchange) so I thought I'd ask here in case someone immediately spots what I've missed.

- $TEXMFHOME => $HOME/texmf
- unzip the file from [1](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/sourcesanspro) and place all files in their correct directory, so tfms are in `~/texmf/fonts/tfm/sourcesanspro` etc. - this is the same directory layout as my `/usr/share/texmf` for the packages installed with the package manager
- run `mktexlsr`/`texhash`, it correctly finds my `~/texmf` directory.
- run `updmap --enable Map=SourceSansPro.map` and `updmap`
- `texhash` again

Here's my test document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\begin{document}
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

And I get (I manually replaced my homedir with `~`):

```
(~/texmf/tex/latex/mweights/mweights.sty))
(./font.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/ly1/ly1ptm.fd)
(~/texmf/tex/latex/sourcesanspro/T1SourceSansPro-LF.f
d) [1{~/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
}] (./font.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 SourceSansPro-Regular-lf-t1--base
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for SourceSansPro-Regular-lf-t1--base.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
)
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file SourceSansPro-Regular-lf-t1--base): Font SourceSansPro-Regular-lf-t1--base at 600 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Ok, let's check for the file:

```
$ find ~/texmf -name 'SourceSansPro-Regular-lf-t1--base*'
~/texmf/fonts/tfm/sourcesanspro/SourceSansPro-Regular-lf-t1--base.tfm
```

What can I try next?

Comment: The problem is not the tfm. pdflatex doesn't find the "real" font. Add `\pdfmapfile{=SourceSansPro.map}` to your document. If it works then you will have to find out why updmap didn't work correcty. E.g. check if it is actually changing the pdftex.map in `~/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map`

Comment: Use `\pdfmapfile{+SourceSansPro.map}` to add the fragment rather than replacing the file. I realise it is only for testing, but it is also a useful way to get stuff working until you figure out the problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 4 is probably what you have been missing. Have a look at it (I was having the same issue with Fira font).

https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex` and the following should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{SourceSansPro}
\begin{document}
    This is a test.
\end{document}
```